# Gauss-Jordan Elimination in C

Tags: c

So, I have some class work that I cannot solve. I could get the code to work partially but now it is just useless. It either freezes (doesn't complete running) or it will give me several inf in the first row.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    double a[10][11]={
{3.55618, 5.87317, 7.84934, 5.6951, 3.84642, 9.15038, -1.68539, 5.03067, 7.63384, -1.75626, -1.92193},
{-4.82893, 8.38177, -0.301221, 5.10182, -4.1169,-6.09145, -3.95675, -2.33365, 1.3969, 6.54555, -2.35262},
{-7.64196, 5.66605, 3.20481, 1.55619, -1.19814, 9.79288, 5.35547, 5.86109, 4.95544, -9.35749, 2.27709},
{-2.95914, -9.16958, 7.3216, 2.39876, -8.1302, -7.55135, -2.37718, 7.29694, 5.9867, 8.5401, -2.67493},
{-8.42043, -0.369407, -5.4102, -8.00545, 9.22153, 3.96454, 5.38499, 0.438365, 0.419677, 4.17166, 1.84756},
{6.02952, 4.57728, 5.46424, 3.52915, -1.01135, -3.74686, 8.14264, -8.86961, -2.88114, 1.29821, 4.154126},
{0.519819, -6.16655, 1.13216, 2.75811, -1.05975, 4.20286, -3.45764, 0.763558, -0.281287, -9.76168, -.93387},
{5.15737, -9.67481, 9.29904, -3.93334, 9.12785, -4.25208, -6.1652, 2.5375, 0.139195, 2.00106, -1.28356},
{-4.30784, 1.40711, -6.97966, -9.29715, 5.17234, 2.42634, 1.88818, -2.05526, -3.7679, 3.3708, -3.46841},
{-4.65418, 7.18118, 6.51338, 3.13249, 0.188456, -16.85599, 7.21435, -2.93417, 1.06061, 1.10807, -2.61529}};
    int i, j, k, l;
    double b[10][11];

    i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
            j=0;
            l=i;
            while(l<10)
            {
                    j=0;
                    l++;
                    while(j<11)
                    {
```

This code below works fine. When used on its own, it will turn all the diagonal values into 1.

```
                            b[i][j]=a[i][j]/a[i][i];
```

This code used below to work partially, setting the first column equal to 0, but now it is useless. I tried to manipulate it into getting rid of all values by having that 0 be a k, with k++ within the while code, but it would return either a segmentation code if I placed it by the i++; or a bus error is placed in front of the j=0;, and it would just freeze the program if I placed the i in the 0. Now it is useless that I restored it to default

```
                            b[l][j]=a[l][j]-b[i][j]*a[l][0];
                            j++;
                    }
            }
            i++;
    }

    j=0;
    i=0;
    while(i<10)
    {
            while(j<11)
            {
                    printf("%lf\t", b[i][j]);
                    j++;
            }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
    j=0;
    }

return 0;
}
```

How do I go about solving all these issues within my C program?

Comment: You've divided your code across boxes making it very difficult to see how it all fits together.  Beyond this, I give you the "Single step in the debugger and see where it goes sideways." Standard response to the question of "Why doesn't it work?"

Comment: To maintain mental sanity, I'd advice to replace all your `while()` loops by `for()` loops. That will not only increase readability, it will also reduce the chance for errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what your code is up to, but I see at least 1 place where I believe that you are reading off the end of your arrays:

```
while(l<10)
{
    j=0;
    l++;
```

...

```
           b[l][j]=a[l][j]-b[i][j]*a[l][0];
```

Because you are incrementing after you check for max size, you have 1 iteration where you are probably reading passed the max size of the array.

To check, put some prints on your indexes in your code where you do your assignments or assert them or something and I think you will find the source of your woes.

Also, PLEASE use constants for your sizes instead of the magic numbers all over the place.  You will thank me later when trying to do a calculation of a matrix of a different size.

Comment: If you down-vote, explain why or what is wrong with my answer please.  I see a case where `l` can go past the size of the array in the area of the code OP called out as being questionable.  What is the issue?